# How to select the first occurrence of an HTML element in CSS that does not have a specific class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to style a specific element inside a datepicker using CSS. Although I thought that it must be super simple using the nth selectors I can't seem to figure out how it is possible.

I have CSS and HTML code like this:

```css
.ui-datepicker tr td:not(.ui-state-disabled) + td:nth-of-type(1)
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="ui-datepicker">
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td>
      This is the td element I like to select
    </td>
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="ui-datepicker">
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td>
      This is the td element I like to select
    </td>
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to select the first `td` element after the last `ui-state-disabled` element. The problem is that the position of that `td` element as well as the number of `td` elements is not always the same. You can see what I tried in the CSS code of the snippet however it is not working. What I am looking for is a "first occurrence" selector. Is there any way to accomplish this using only CSS?

Comment: Have you tried a combination of last-of-type plus adjacent sibling? 
`td.ui-state-disabled:last-of-type + td { }`

Comment: Why do you need to use CSS instead of JavaScript?

Comment: What a pity, I thought this is kind of a common problem that is possible to solve with CSS. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
td.ui-state-disabled + td:not(.ui-state-disabled) {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="ui-datepicker">
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="ui-datepicker">
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td class="ui-state-disabled">
      ...
    </td>
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow so simple! Sometimes you just don't see the obvious. Thank you :)